# Why can't I copy from my mac and paste to my iPad in Universal Clipboards?

Tags: ipad, macos, ios, copy-paste

It's strange and probably not a duplicate question (since I've read a lot of questions with this issue, but none match with my problem).

I believe I've setup everything correctly. In fact, I can copy from my iPad and paste to my mac using Universal Clipboards, no problem. But the other way is not working: I can't copy text from my mac and paste to my iPad.

I've reset iPad, and it's working again. Copy from mac, paste to iPad. But only after a while, it's not working again.

Actual stuff: I was having a list of issues, and I'm trying to create a tasks for each issue in my ipad's asana app. Just copy text from mac, trying to paste to asana task as a title. About first 3 copy-paste, it works, but the 4th or 5th copy-paste, it's not working anymore (just like before reset iPad). Copy from ipad and paste to mac still working.

How do I resolve this universal clipboard stuff?

PS: apple.stackexchange really should have a tag name: Universal clipboards

Comment: What universal clipboard are you using?

Comment: @john what? are there other universal clipboards? of course, it's the one where you shared clipboard with your apple devices!

Comment: I have Notefile, Klipboard, and Nice Clipboard.  I got all 3 to test them. They all work as advertised.  I have copies on my iMac and iPad.  Copies made from either device shows up on both.  I suppose thats what you meant by universal.  If not I'm really sorry.

Comment: So you use 3rd party stuff for the universal clipboard. I just use the default one, provided by Apple themselves.

Comment: @Eddie did you manage to get a solution? I'm having a similar issue but I can copy from Mac and paste to iPhone but not the other way round...

Comment: @Frakcool I’m not sure but it’s been sometime since I last experienced this. I just update to latest version and it seems it got better.

Comment: I have latest versions of iOS and MacOS @Eddie I guess I'll have to try restarting both devices, iCloud, etc to see if it gets better. Thanks

Comment: it seems like this issue occurs randomly. probably a bug from Apple.